# C# XAML (WPF) add button to image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, button

I Have this code:

```
<Button >
      <Button.Content>
            <Image Source="component/Resources/Homer.jpg" />
      </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

This create an image as part of a button
But i want to do the opposite thing, i want to have an image and make a button a part od that image

something like:

```
<Image >
     <Button>
     </Button>
</Image>
```

Is it possible?
if yes, how?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not directly possible.

The reason is that the [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Class is designed to display an image, not host controls, and thus does not implement a content or inherit from [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) the way other hosting objects do.

While there no little reason I can fathom NOT to place an Image in a Button, there are a few options.

- While Image does not implement a Click event, you can use [Preview
  Mouse Down](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousedown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a similar effect.
- You can place both a Button and an Image in a Grid, causing them to share the same space

> ```
> <Grid >
>     <Button ... HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
>     <Image ... />
> </Grid >
> ```

Comment: Thank you, doesn't my first code and your second point will give me the same resolt (visualy)?

Comment: Yes, this should be the same result, visually, but bears mention since you wanted an alternate solution